# How do I post to Gwibber from python?

Tags: application-development, quickly, gwibber

How do I post to Gwibber from python?

I have tried

```
import gwibber.utils
foo = gwibber.utils.GwibberPublic()
foo.post("This is a test message")
```

from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly/Snippets.

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You should really be using the GIR based API, here is a more current example:

```
from gi.repository import Gwibber

s = Gwibber.Service ()
s.send_message ("This is the content to post", None, None, None)
```

That will post to all accounts that are currently enabled to send.  Here are what the parameters for send_message are:

```
"""
  send_message: Posts a message
  @message: The message to post to Gwibber as a string or None
  @id: The gwibber message id or None
  @action: The action or None (reply, private)
  @account_id: The ID of the account to post from or None
"""
```

So if you want to only post from a specific account, you can do something like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gwibber
accounts_service = Gwibber.Accounts.new ()
s = Gwibber.Service ()

accts = accounts_service.list () # A list of Gwibber.Account objects
for acct in accts:
    print "Gwibber ID: %s, Service: %s, Username: %s, Send: %s" % (acct.props.id, acct.props.service, acct.props.username, "True" if acct.props.send_enabled == "1" else "False")
    #add code to check if this is the account you want to post from, like if you want to post from all twitter accounts you would do this
    if acct.props.service == "twitter":
        s.send_message ("Whatever you want to post", None, None, acct.props.id)
```

Comment: Fair point Ken. I have deleted mine to prevent misleading others.

Comment: from gi.repository import Gwibber
ImportError: cannot import name Gwibber

Comment: glen@glen-desktop:~/calorie-burner$ locate girepository | grep Gwibber
glen@glen-desktop:~/calorie-burner$

Comment: You need to install gir1.2-gwibber-0.2