# How do I add a Gwibber entry widget to my app?

Tags: application-development, gwibber, widgets

I am writing an app which has a button that, when clicked, should launch a Gwibber entry widget. This used to work, as suggested [on the tutorial](https://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/ubuntu-developer-stack/notification/adding-social-networking-support-to-your-app/):

```
from gi.repository import GwibberGtk
entry = GwibberGtk.Entry()
add(entry)
```

But now it doesn't anymore on my computer. I encountered the error `ImportError: cannot import name GwibberGtk`. So, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152882/how-do-i-post-to-gwibber-from-python), I installed `gir1.2-gwibber-0.2` and I changed the first line of my code into

```
from gi.repository import Gwibber
```

But the problem is that this "Gwibber" object has no "Entry" method. What should I use to create an entry widget as before ? Will the method you advice me be compatible on computers on which my app will be distributed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GwibberGtk is correct, you need gir1.2-gwibber-gtk-0.2